# "Unfortunate Son" meaning?

Tags: phrase-requests, colloquialisms

My wife recently came upon the will & testament of some long past relatives.  In these documents the man leaves several slaves for the care of his "Unfortunate son".  The term "Unfortunate Son" is used a few times. We've also found other documents where that term pops up again, not only with that particular son, but another a decade or two later.

While Googling I can't find a definable answer as to what it means.  Was he mentally challenged? Born out of wedlock?  Born of a relationship with a slave?

The will was written in the 1830s in Georgia.

Comment: Could you tell us what time period and in what part of the world your relatives might have lived. Slavery has been outlawed for a very long time in much of the world so presumably the meaning is archaic and of a particular period.

Comment: @Bitterdreggs. A quick check to the OP's bio shows they reside in Texas. Presumably the time period was prior to 1865.

Comment: @Rattler Without the OP's input we can only make assumptions and guesses.

Comment: In reading the old documents, were there any other instances of seemingly inappropriate usage of caps? It might have been a personal quirk of the writer, or possibly even the style of the time.

Comment: The will was written in the 1830s in Georgia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending upon the original ancestry of the relatives, this entry in the OED might be the one:

> **Unfortunate**: 3. *Irish English*. An idiot.
>   1881   Folk Lore Rec. IV. 113   Do you see that ‘innocent’ or ‘unfortunate’ or ‘object’?

In modern English this would be "mentally challenged."

Comment: This could be it since her family originated from Ireland.

Answer (score 0):

Often with archaic usage, a term means what it means at face value, without the implications added through years of usage. In modern usage, for example, we take the word "unfortunate" to mean "unlucky" in any or all areas of life. In the past, however, its root word "fortune" was associated primarily with material wealth.

In this case, I believe the term "[unfortunate](https://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/unfortunate) son" would be best understood to mean a child who was not financially well off. In the context of a last will and testament, this meaning makes perfect sense.